# How to parse string Date fields in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to parse this one?

> Date.parse("Sunday May sixth, Ten Fifteen AM Two thousand fourteen")

or

> Date.parse("Sunday May sixth, Ten Fifteen Two thousand fourteen AM")

Comment: Have a look at the Chronic gem if you want to get into natural language parsing of dates.  https://github.com/mojombo/chronic

Comment: Is this a standard format, or a custom one? How lenient is it?

Comment: Useful link: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Natural_Language_Date_Parsing

Comment: An even better solution (if you have any control over the input at all) is to just get the data source to give you a sensible, non-ambiguous date string. In what age are people inputting dates this way?

Comment: i think **Chronic** will not support seconds.